# Clang libtooling: determine macro expansion location

Tags: clang, llvm, libtooling

I have a header `header.h` with a macro definition which expands into a class definition and a source file `test.cpp` which includes `header.h` and uses this macro. Then I use `RecursiveASTVisitor` to visit all `CXXRecordDecl`'s.

When I visit the CXXRecordDecl which is expansion of the macro (in test.cpp) and query for its `SourceLocation` and `dump()` it, the location points to `header.h` - the location of macro definition.

What I need to get for this CXXRecordDecl is the `SourceLocation` of macro expansion - in my case it should be `test.cpp`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found solution.

The required method is SourceManager's [getFileLoc(SourceLocation loc)](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html#a0a48eea62efa1672fb1da24a310d36db), which "returns the expansion location" if `loc` "is a macro location".

My code to get source location for both normal class definitions and definitions as macro expansions:

```
bool VisitCXXRecordDecl(CXXRecordDecl* record)
{
    SourceLocation loc = record->getLocStart();
    SourceLocation locExp = m_sourceManager.getFileLoc(loc);
    // if record is a macro expansion in test.cpp, locExp points to test.cpp
    // if record is not a macro expansion, locExp correctly points to matching source file
}
```